# Check if values are present in an array based on another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$check` which has codes associated to offer and basket - both of these have key values. I would like to check if the values in `basket` are present in `offer`.

Scenario 1, this would fail because basket does not contain DEF:

```
Array
(
    [offer] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'ABC',
            [1] => 'DEF',
        ),
    [basket] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'ABC',
            [1] => '123',
            [2] => '456',
        )
)
```

Scenario 2, this would pass because basket array contains both ABC and DEF

```
Array
(
    [offer] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'ABC',
            [1] => 'DEF',
        ),
    [basket] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'ABC',
            [1] => 'DEF',
            [2] => '123',
        )
)
```

What's the most effective way to compare the arrays?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem yourself? Show some code.

Comment: `array_intersect` function.

Comment: Everyone knows that _What is the most efficient way to ...._ Actualy means ___write it for me.___ First you should write code that works, then, and only if necessary, attempt to optimise it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you showed no effort in solving your problem, make effort in understanding this):

```
echo count($check['offer']) == count(array_intersect($check['basket'], $check['offer'])) ? 'All present' : 'Nope';
```

Comment: :):):):):):):):)